# XLSForms PULL Data

Tags: webforms, constraints, data-collection, kobotoolbox, xlsform

please I need a help in an issue where I want the pull data function not to run when a specific field has an answer

[**the image describes exactly what I have**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOaOy.png)

for example in the image above , no need to pull data when the field "Mohafaza" already have an answer , it is pulling data and overwrite my edits if I save the form as draft and re-open it

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code in your `calculation` column for row `Mohafaza` from:

```
${Mohafazacheck}
```

to:

```
if(${Mohafaza}='', ${Mohafazacheck}, ${Mohafaza})
```

Every time you re-open the form, it will only replace `Mohafaza` if the question doesn't have an answer already.